# Custom vector's clear function

Tags: c++, templates, vector

```
template <class DataType> /// Declaring the template class Datatype
class Vector
{   public:
    Vector()
    {m_data = new DataType[9999]; 
      m_size = 1;

        m_current = 0;
    }

    Vector(int size)  /// Constructing vector
    { m_data = new DataType[size]; 
      m_size = size;
      m_current = -1;
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////
    /// Creating Push and Pop methods
    ///////////////////////////////////////

    bool push(const DataType data) 
    { if (m_current < m_size)
      { m_current++;
        m_data[m_current] = data;
        return true;
      }
      else
      { return false; }
    }

    bool pop(DataType &data)
    { if (m_current==-1)
      { cout << "Nothing to pop";
        return false;
      }
      else
      { data = m_data[m_current];
        m_current--;
        return true;
      }
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////
    /// Methods to access the private m_data
    ///////////////////////////////////////

    float retrievefloat(int pointer) 
    {
        return m_data[pointer];
    }

    string retrievestring(int pointer)
    {
        return m_data[pointer];
    }

    int retrieveint(int pointer)
    {
        return m_data[pointer];
    }

    int retrievecurrent()
    {
        return m_current;
    }

    int retrievesize()
    {
        return m_size;
    }

private:

    DataType* m_data;
    int m_size;
    int m_current;
};
```

Ok, here we have a custom templated vector class. The problem here is, I wish to include a `clear()` function. I know pretty much you can just do `int m_size = 0` and `int m_current = -1`. But how do you reset m_data?

Trying `delete [] m_data` crashes the program when I want to push data in again after calling the `clear` function.

Comment: The real vector treats memory allocations and construction of elements in this memory separately. Clear operation then just destruct the elements, but leaves the memory allocated. Since you are doing both at the same time (`new DataType[9999]`), clear operation does not make much sense, since you cannot destruct the elements (then, `delete[]` would be undefined). If you `delete[]` in `clear` instead, you container will seemingly not be in the valid state (default-constructed).

Answer (score 0):

Where should I begin... Now, this is not a **vector** class, but a **stack** class.

There are a lot of issues with your code, but to address your initial problem, you should not delete m_data in your `clear()` method. Normally, a user of your class would not read objects outside the range of what has been pushed, so no need to delete or realloc. Also, since all, and only, your constructors set the size of your vector and allocate it, you expect it not to change, and assume your m_data buffer is always allocated. After a clear, there would be no place to push your data!

Here's what it COULD be, to your standard:

```
void clear()
{
    m_current = -1;
}
```

Take a look at this revised, but far from complete, snippet. Have fun finishing it...

```
template<typename DataType> /// Declaring the template class Datatype
class Vector
{
public:
    Vector(size_t size = 9999)  /// Constructing vector
    {
        if (size == 0)
        {
            size = 9999;
        }
        m_data = new DataType[size]; 
        m_size = size;
        m_current = -1;
    }

    void clear()
    {
        m_current = -1;
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////
    /// Creating Push and Pop methods
    ///////////////////////////////////////

    bool push(const DataType data) 
    { if (m_current < m_size)
      { m_current++;
        m_data[m_current] = data;
        return true;
      }
      else
      { return false; }
    }

    bool pop(DataType &data)
    { if (m_current==-1)
      { cout << "Nothing to pop";
        return false;
      }
      else
      { data = m_data[m_current];
        m_current--;
        return true;
      }
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////
    /// Methods to access the private m_data
    ///////////////////////////////////////

    bool retrieveat(size_t index, DataType &data)
    {
      if (index>=m_size)
      {
        return false;
      }
      data = m_data[index];
      return true;
    }

    int retrievecurrent()
    {
        return m_current;
    }

    size_t retrievesize()
    {
        return m_size;
    }

private:

    DataType* m_data;
    size_t m_size;
    int m_current;
};
```